# Calculated column with the sum of values from many columns in a row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to sum all values in each row and display them in a calculated column. As I deal with lots of columns in lots of tables, adding something like

```
CalculatedColumn = 'public table_name'[column1] + 'public table_name'[column2] + ... + 'public table_name'[column528]
```

is really inefficient. **Is there a shorter way of doing this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You should **"Unpivot other columns" and then "Group By"** using the Query Editor.

1. Suppose this dataset:

   ```
   item;col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
   apple;1;2;3;4;5
   orange;1;2;3;5;8
   banana;1;2;4;6;8
   ```
2. Load it up, and open the query editor.
3. Choose "Unpivot Other Columns":

   [image: Unpivot Other Columns]

   You should now see this:

   [image: unpivoted view]
4. On the "Transform" tab in the ribbon, choose the leftmost "Group By" option. And fill out the dialog like so:

   [image: group by]
5. You should now have the wanted end result:

   [image: summarized view]

You could also skip the Group By step and let your visualization handle that.

PS. Should you need a few non-summed columns too I recommend either creating a duplicate dataset with the same source and either *linking* it to the original table with a relationship, or *merging* it so you get a final table with all wanted columns.

---

Footnote, this is the Power Query that is generated for you:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\Experiments\PowerBi\denormalized.csv"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"item", type text}, {"col1", Int64.Type}, {"col2", Int64.Type}, {"col3", Int64.Type}, {"col4", Int64.Type}, {"col5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"item"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"item"}, {{"SumCol", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```